# Nginx x-frame-options config not blocking Angular SPA dynamically loading pages

Tags: angular, nginx, single-page-application

I am trying to set Nginx config to block my site being embedded into an iFrame - except for one url.
My config looks like this:

```
    location / {
      expires -1;
      add_header X-Frame-Options "DENY";
      add_header Pragma "no-cache";
      add_header Cache-Control "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0";
      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html = 404;
    }

    location /search {
      add_header X-Frame-Options "";
      expires -1;
      add_header Pragma "no-cache";
      add_header Cache-Control "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0";
      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html = 404;
    }
```

As per the config, any iFrame traffic that is directed to the /search path is allowed through, but traffic to any other location is blocked.

The problem is if the iFrame is initially pointed to the /search path and then the user clicks on a link to navigate to a different page, the navigation is not blocked and the user can get through.

I feel that this is happening because the application is an Angular based SPA, therefore navigation to a different path is not being done with a full browser refresh.

Any way I can allow the /search path to be shown in an iFrame, yet block all traffic to anywhere else in the site - no matter how the user got there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out.

When navigating to a different page, as the Angular app is minified and bundled to the main.js file, no actual requests are being made to the server and therefore the request does not get to Nginx. Therefore no blocking is done.

A potential solution would be to make proper use of separate application modules and have them bundled separately.